# css background-repeat x and y

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to use with small picture for the background div to repeat x and y together?
[See example
thanks.](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/p2vjf/5/)

Answer (score 21):

```
background-repeat: repeat;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp:

> repeat - The background image will be repeated both vertically and
>   horizontally. This is default

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/p2vjf/6/

Comment: You can completely omit the `background-repeat` property anyway. As mentioned, this is the default value.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, just remove both, and the default value `background-repeat: repeat;` kicks in:

http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/p2vjf/7/

Answer (score 2):

use this....

```
float: left;
width: 100%;
background: url(../images/img01.jpg) left top repeat;
height: 500px;  //set the height to which you want to repeat
```